# How to align spinner and textview in android table layout?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm creating one table layout with text view and spinner.

My textview content is too large, so it's wrapped up in my layout. Whenever the textview having wrapped, the same row spinner also increased the height.

My code is,

```
<TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/trConfigPeriodStop" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvConfigPeriodStop"
                android:text="Periodic reporting interval while moving"    
                android:layout_weight="0.5"           
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/gpsblue"                      
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spnConfigPeriodStop"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"                
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:entries="@array/periodstop_arrays"
                android:prompt="@string/periodstop_prompt"                                               
                />
        </TableRow>
```

Suppose I'm changing the layout height in wrap_content in spinner, that time my text view text also hide from view.

How to solve this issue?
Please do the needful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  layout height as wrap_content for both Spinner and TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/trConfigPeriodStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"  
    android:textColor="@color/gpsblue"    
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvConfigPeriodStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Periodic reporting interval while moving" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnConfigPeriodStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:entries="@array/periodstop_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/periodstop_prompt"  />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it is because **tablerow has**  **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** and inner **textview has android:layout_height="fill_parent"**, so the height of the tablerow will fit to the height of the spinner, that is the only child with fixed and independent height while rendering.

you will solve it if you change    **TextView's** height also to **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**